# How to do selected single product should be purchase alone?

Tags: orders, addtocart, magento1.9.2.3, restriction

I have one restricted product, here how to do selected single product should be purchased alone? No other products are eligible to add add-to-cart if this product available in the add-to-cart, same if other products available in add-to-cart this product not eligible to add add-to-cart.

Workout->  https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/d68943de1e0b0def488bddcdf4ada4c9 not working.

Comment: Do it by `beforeAddProduct()` plugin method

Comment: @KetanBorada I Really appreciate your answer, could you pls explain in brief?